# Pass custom image on add to cart

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I'm trying to replicate the behavior that this site has:
http://pixers.es/fotomurales/hermosa-mujer-ejemplo-de-la-acuarela-59301559

As you can see you can select a certain portion of the image to buy it. 
If you select any size and click `add to cart` it passes the selection to the cart.

I have managed to put the jCrop to create the custom selection (http://pixelbypixel.comli.com/jcrop/) but I don't know what would be the best way to pass this selection to the `add to cart` button (in woocommerce) and replace the actual product image on the cart with the selection.

I have found this: https://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201449733-Is-there-a-Woocommerce-before-or-after-add-to-cart-hook-I-can-use-for-my-custom-plugin-

So I guess this would be the way to start:

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_js' );
    function custom_enqueue_js() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/your-file-path/filename.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    }

    (function($) {
      $(document).off( 'click', '.add_to_cart_button' );
      $(document).on( 'click', '.add_to_cart_button', function() {
        //your code here
      });
    });
```

Any ideas what would be the way to do this?